# $G=H\times K$ and $H,K$ have no common direct factor but $H$ or $K$ is not characteristic in $G$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I was searching for an example of a group $G=H\times K$ where $H,K$ have no common direct factor (i.e. there is no $L\neq 1$ such that $H\cong H_1\times L$ and $K\cong K_1\times L$), but $H$ or $K$ is not characteristic. Can one suggest example, and possibly of smallest order?

The natural way to consider $H,K$ without direct factor would be consider them of relatively prime order, but then they would become characteristic.

Comment: If the condition is "i.e. there is no $L\neq 1$ such that $H\cong H_1\times L$ $\underline{\text{and}}$ $K\cong K_1\times L$" then $H:=\mathbb{Z}/2\times \mathbb{Z}/2$ and $K:=\mathbb{Z}/2$ works. Maybe you wanted to write : "i.e. there is no $L\neq 1$ such that $H\cong H_1\times L$ $\underline{\text{or}}$ $K\cong K_1\times L$"

Comment: @ClémentGuérin I don't think your example works. ${\mathbb Z}/2$ is a common direct factor.

Comment: $H=C_4$ and $K=C_2$ is an example, and probably the smallest such,

Comment: @Holt: Yes; simple example, and here both $H$ and $K$ are non-characteristic subgroups.